# How to run ES6 React app in IE9 without errors

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-9, babeljs

I am working on a JS app using React 0.14 and Babel 5.8.23.

My app works fine in Chrome, with no warnings, but when I view the app in IE9 the app explodes showing:

`SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught`

on the line

`ReactDOM.render(`

When I trap the exception, it shows that it is being thrown from this code:

`function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }`

When I manually remove these throws from the generated `index.js`, the app proceeds normally, although I do see these warnings (possibly unrelated, and discussed at https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4990):

`Warning: MainLogo(...): React component classes must extend React.Component`

All my components do extend React.Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MainLogo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1 className="logo">
        <img src="/img/brand/logo.png" />
      </h1>
    );
  }
};
```

Why would this `_classCallCheck` be being triggered in IE9, and what could I do differently to prevent it?

Comment: Does including babel/polyfill solve this problem? https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the following are problems for IE9:

#### 1.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Whatever extends Component { ...
```

I had to `import React;` and then `... extends React.Component`.

#### 2.

I had to export my `connect`ed components as non-top-level components, ie giving them a name within the file:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export const AppContainer = connect(state => ({ routerState: state.router }), { pushState }) (App);
```

#### 3.

I had to disable `livereactload` https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload, specifically removing it from `.babelrc` used by `babel-plugin-react-transform`.

Only completing ALL these steps allowed my app to run satisfactorily on IE9.

Comment: Does including babel/polyfill solve this problem? https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: Any issues with defaultProps? I'm on react v0.14.7 setting onClick to be a noop and ie9 is finding it undefined.